# Has one through Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have three tables `garages`, `cars`, `securities`.

The securities are the ones that is keeping one car safe, you can have more than one security, but a single security can keep only one car safe. The garage is where the car is and the securities are as well.

What I want is to list all the securities and know the name of the garage that he is. The problem is that `securities` doesn't have a column containing the id of the garage, only the id of the car that he is keeping safe, but car has the id of the garage.

Laravel Eloquent has a method called `hasManyThrough`, but `securities` has one `garage` through `cars` only.

Here is the tables:

garages table:

```
-----------------------------------
|garage_id|garage_name|garage_size|
-----------------------------------
|        1|   Garage 1|        200|
-----------------------------------
|        2|   Garage 2|        400|
-----------------------------------
```

cars table:

```
---------------------------
|car_id|car_name|garage_id|
---------------------------
|     1|   Car 1|        1|
---------------------------
|     2|   Car 2|        1|
---------------------------
|     3|   Car 3|        2|
---------------------------
```

securities table:

```
----------------------------------
|security_id|security_name|car_id|
----------------------------------
|          1|  Security 1|      1|
----------------------------------
|          2|  Security 2|      1|
----------------------------------
|          3|  Security 3|      2|
----------------------------------
|          4|  Security 4|      3|
----------------------------------
```

The output must to be:

```
Security 1 is on Garage 1
Security 2 is on Garage 1
Security 3 is on Garage 1
Security 4 is on Garage 2
```

And I have the models:

The code is to list the garages, but I want to make similar but to list the securities (just for you to have an idea of how the structure is).

```
$garages = Garages::with(['cars', 'securities'])->get();

$garages->transform(function($garages) {
    return array(
        'garage_name'      => $garage->garage_name,
        'count_cars'       => $garage->cars->count(),
        'count_securities' => $garage->securities->count(),
   );
});

class Garages extends Eloquent
{
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('cars');
    }

    public function securities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('securities');
    }
}

class Cars extends Eloquent
{
}

class Securities extends Eloquent
{
}
```

And just to make an emphasis again: **I want to have the name of the garage related to the car that the security is keeping safe.**

Just to make it even easier to understand, if I do this:

```
$securities = Securities::with(['cars'])->get();

class Securities extends Eloquent
{
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('cars');
    }
}
```

I will get only the `garage_id` from `cars` table as relations. What I really want is the name of the garage.

```
[relations:protected] => Array
    (
        [cars] => Cars Object
            (
                ...
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        ...
                        [car_name] => Car 1
                        [garage_id] => 1
                        ...
```

Comment: check out https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep#hasonedeep

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It looks like you are not relating objects correctly. Let's break that down:

If a `Garage` Has Many `Car` then a `Car` Belongs To `Garage`, Lets proceed with this idea in mind.

- `Garage` Has Many `Car`
- `Car` Has Many `Security`
- `Security` Belongs To `Car`
- `Garage` Has Many `Security` Through `Car`

In Eloquent you can just go ahead and clap those relations in, it should work given the schema you posted above.

```
class Garage extends Eloquent
{
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('cars');
    }

    public function securities()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Security', 'Car');
    }
}

class Car extends Eloquent
{
    public function securities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Security');
    }

    // ADDED IN SECOND EDIT

    public function garage()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Garage');
    }       
}

class Security extends Eloquent
{
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Car');
    }
}
```

And that should be it.

**EDIT:** You can access all these relations from any model as long as there is a path you can draw from one model to another using a combination of these relations. Check this out for example:

```
$security = Security::with('car.garage')->first();
```

will retrieve first `Security` record and load `Car` relation on it, then it goes one more step and load all `Garage` relations on every `Car` object loaded under `Security` model.

You can access them using this syntax:

```
$security->car->garage->id

// Other examples
$garage = Garage::with('cars.securities')->first();

foreach($garage->cars as $car)
{
    foreach($cars->securities as $security)
    {
        echo "Car {$car->id} has {$security->id} assigned to it";
    }
}
```

Furthermore, notice that the relationship objects are an instance of `Collection` so you have all the fancy methods such as `->each()`, `->count()`, `->map()` available on them.

Comment: I don't understand how I'm going to retrieve the name of the garage now. Because if I do this: `$securities = Securities::with(['cars'])->get();` still returning only the id of the user.

Comment: You can nest relationship using dot operator, like this: `Security::with('car', 'car.garage')`

Comment: @MrAlmighty I edited the answer to add more information. go through it once again.

Comment: AMAZING. Thank you very much. I didn't knew that was possible to nest relationships.

Comment: yup this works perfectly OneThing->haveOtherThing->haveAnotherThing    OneThing::where('rules')->with('OtherThing.AnotherThing')->first();

Comment: But the question was about hasOneThrough, and literally every example has been given except for the one that was asked about.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into a similar problem recently and was able to do something like this:

```
class Cars extends Eloquent
{
    public function garage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Garages');
    }
}

class Securities extends Eloquent
{
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Cars');
    }

    public function garage()
    {
        return $this->car->garage();
    }
}
```

This gives you the Securities has one garage relationship and you can do something like:

```
$securities = Securities::with('garage')->get();

foreach($securities as $security)
{
    echo $security->security_name . ' is on ' . $security->garage->garage_name;
}
```

Comment: +1: Although [Gufran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27470639/2286722) is more elaborate and generalized, this answer actually answers the question: how to create the hasOne model relationship from `Securities` to `Garages`.

Answer (score 6):

This is relevant to your original inquiry.

hasOneThrough will be available in Laravel 5.8

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26057/files

Comment: Here is the hasOneThrough() source code:  https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneThrough.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use `hasOneThrough`, integrated on Laravel => 5.8.

```
public function garage()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        Garage::class,
        Car::class,
        'car_id',
        'id',
        null,
        'garage_id'
    );
}
```

Dont use solutions like

```
return $this->car->garage();
```

Because it are using eager loading, and you call to database on each iteration. These type of solution are not optimized.