# has one through relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i was reading here:

[Has one through Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466542/has-one-through-laravel-eloquent)

but it does not solve the problem

we have manufacturerer names, for example:

```
kohler company
kohler
Kohler US
```

and these names we bundle together in one single clean name -> `Kohler`

so we have a table

`manufacturer`

and one

`manufacturer_bundle`

there exist `products` created by those manufacturers

so a product has a manufacturer, and a manufacturer is linked to a manufacturer bundle.

But: not all products have a manufacturer entered. it can be empty. Or the manufacturer is not assigned to a manufacturer bundle.

I want to  have a function

`$product->manufacturer_bundle`

currently i have to do

`$product->manufacturer->manufacturer_bundle`

I cannot write a function

```
public function manufacturer_bundle(){
  return $this->manufacturer->manufacturer_bundle;
}
```

because `$this->manufacturer` might be empty and I return nothing, I get an error: "Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation" . What is the correct laravel way to do this?

Comment: `$this->hasOne(Manufacturer::class);` <-- `hasOne` `hasMany` `belongsTo` so forth are returning `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` which tell you to firstly _create a relationship_ before trying to _relate each other_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hasOneThrough` relationship has been added with version 5.8

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

Answer (score 4):

ok .. you have three models ..

first is the **ManufacturerBundle** model as the peak of the hierarchy , add a function inside

```
public function manufacturers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Manufacturers', 'bundle_id');
}

public function products(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Products','App\Manufacturer','bundle_id','manufacturer_id');
}
```

model table structure must have:

```
'id' as primary key
'name' as the name of the manufacturer bundle
'and so on' . . . . . .
```

second is the **Manufacturer** model, that have data such as kohler company, kohler and Kohler US .. this model must belong to the manufacturer_bundle .. so we do inside the model a function like

```
public function bundle(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ManufacturerBundle');
}
```

and so this also must have the products it have .. so

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Products','manufacturer_id');
}
```

model table structure must have:

```
'id' as primary key
'bundle_id' as the model manufacturerbundle id
'name' as the name of the manufacturer
'and so on' . . . . . .
```

as the last and the bottom of the hierarchy , we have **Product** model .. that should also belongs to the manufacturer .. so in the model we add a function

```
public function manufacturer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Manufacturer');
}
```

model table structure must have:

```
'id' again as primary key
'manufacturer_id' as the model manufacturer id
'name' as product name
'and so on' . . . . . . fields you want to add
```

and so the relations of our three model are now set. how you have several ways to call them

**first** using the bundle ..

```
$bundles = ManufacturerBundle::with('manufacturers.products')->get();
```

> this will return you all bundles including it's manufacturer and their products ..

```
$bundles = ManufacturerBundle::with('products')->get();
```

> this will return you all bundles including all products that belongs to the manufacturer this bundle have ..

**second** is by the product

```
$products = Product::with('manufacturer.bundle')->get();
```

> this will return all products with their corresponding manufacturer and where this manufacturer is bundled. also those who do not have manufacturer will just leave its manufacturer as empty.

Comment: this is all very correct, it doesn't answer though, how I can do:
`$product->manufacturer_bundle` 
yes your answer is performance optimized to retrieve the records with the `->with` function. But all I do not want to do is `$product->manufacturer->manufacturer_bundle` i want to straight be able to do `$product->manufacturer_bundle`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [model mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators)

In your case i should go for an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

For example:

```
public function getManufacturerBundleAttribute()
{
    return $this->manufacturer->manufacturer_bundle;
}
```

Comment: it isn't an attribute though. I mean, this could work?! but it seems more like a hack, because it really isn't an attribute