# How to link relationship table in laravel, I found on stackoverflow but didnt fully understand

Tags: laravel

Follows my DB structure:

```
surveys 
->id 
->name 
->version 

answers 
->id 
 ->user_id 
 ->question_survey_id 
 ->content

questions 
->id 
->type 
->title 

 question_survey 
 ->id 
 ->question_id 
 ->survey_id

  users 
  ->id 
  ->name
```

These are my models

```
class Survey extends Model
{
  public function questions(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
   }
}

class Question extends Model
{   
   public function surveys(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Survey::class);
   }
}

// in User model
public function answers(){
   return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
}

// in Answer model
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}
```

How to connect **answer with questions** table via key `question_survey_id`? Answer table to `question_survey` table is One-to-One relationship... :)

**If the question is unclear dont down vote and ask me, thanks**

Comment: the relationship questions and surveys is on pivot table question_survey, it works, also users and answers it works too, but how to link from users to questions by using question_survey_id

Comment: Do you already have your models set up?

Comment: `question_survey_id` is belongsTo which table ? how can be `id` repeat in `question_survey` table. better add your model in question

Comment: @alariva , ok i add my models this the relationship

Comment: @rkj sorry i have do correction this the new update

Comment: do you have model for `question_survey` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model for `question_survey` table named `QuestionSurvey` and then add one more relation in `Question` model like this

Question Model

```
public function questionSurveys(){
    return $this->hasMany(QuestionSurvey::class,'question_id');
}
```

QuestionSurvey Model

```
protected $table = "question_survey";

public function answer(){
    return $this->hasOne(Answer::class,'question_survey_id');
}
```

Now you can use these relation to fetch

```
$questions = Question::with('questionSurveys.answer')->get();

foreach($questions as $question){
   foreach($question->questionSurveys as $questionSurvey) {
      echo "Answer=". $questionSurvey->answer->content;
   }
}
```

Comment: means put another table between answer and questions?

Comment: no, you just need to create a model for `question_survey` table. You have this table already

Comment: i think you don't need `survey_id` in questions table

Comment: i try this approach but tinker doesnot see the class 
QuestionSurvey::find(1) basically will show the id in question_survey but it didnt

Comment: do you created `QuestionSurvey` model ?

Comment: yup I create and put the protected $table="question_survey"

Comment: it has another bugs though, try to make another approach

Comment: @ammar the accepted answer is wrong, because `question_survey_id` belongs to `question_survey` table primary key then how can it be has relation with answer table with this field

Comment: Demonyowh i try his solution , it works but a little bit will use more space right?

Comment: did you try my solution ? It is with your existing table structure except remove the `survey_id` from questions table

Comment: its  work perfectly, but i modified some code to meet the relationship

Answer (score 1):

Since your DB keys are customized for Laravel assumption, you need to specify the key name with extra parameters. [See reference here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

```
class Question extends Model
{
   // ...
   public function answer(){
        return $this->hasOne(Answer::class, 'question_survey_id');
   }
   // ...
}

class Answer extends Model
{
   // ...
   public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class, 'question_survey_id');
   }
   // ...
}
```

Comment: seems the questions can get the answer, but answer cannot get questions
i try in tinker Question::find(1)->answer works
while Answer::find(1)->question it give an error

Comment: public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class, 'question_survey_id');
   }
i remove id and it works perfectly

Comment: Cool, I'll edit the answer. Feel free to mark as solved.

Comment: How about I want from answer to get surveys , it is possible? 

example
Answer::find(1)->surveys

Comment: @ammar Thats a new question. Fortunately you have a very well explanation in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466542/has-one-through-laravel-eloquent). Basically check out the `hasManyThrough` relationship.

Comment: nice try brother, you are awesome, but i find another solution, thanks for spend time with me, love you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Best Relation Approach**

1. Survey belongsToMany Question
2. Question belongsToMany Survey

> this way you won't repeat questions for each survey in case you have
>   two same questions with two different surveys.

3. Question hasMany Answer where survey_id = Question->Survey
4. Answer belongsTo User

**Models**

Survey

```
public function questions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'survey_questions', 'survey_id', 'question_id');
}
```

Question

```
public function survey() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Survey::class, 'survey_questions', 'question_id', 'survey_id');
}

public function answers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class)->where('survey_id', $this->survey->id);
}
```

Answer

```
public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

**Databases**

tbl_surveys

- id
- survey_name

tbl_questions

- id
- question

tbl_survey_questions

- id
- survey_id
- question_id

tbl_answers

- id
- user_id
- answer
- question_id
- survey_id

tbl_users

- id
- name

i do hope you do know what to do next ..

Comment: i will try this approach, will let you know ASAP.

Comment: question `hasMany` answer but with `where` clause .. so it will get only answers from a single survey ..

Comment: this approach works well but will be use some space because it will duplicate though, good solutions btw